# How to rank candidates for a jobrole based on historical data

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-science, recommendation-engine

I am working on a ML problem

I have historical data of accepted candidates

Attributes available are

- Education
- Experience
- Compensation
  Keywords which are found in his resume

Using this historical data I have to recommend top 10 candidates suitable for the jobrole from a pool of 100000+ candidates

Please suggest what approach I should take

I have just got the historical data yet

Comment: Hello. What's "1L+ candidates"? Also note facebook tried that once, and the supervised learning model learned that they had been sexist in their recruiting in the past, and thus the model recommended being sexist in the future (since it's basically trained to reproduce the past).

Comment: I meant 1 lac +

Comment: I am not taking gender as an attribute. Any suggestions how this can be done

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So, "1L+" means "1 lac +". Now I have to ask: what does "1 lac +" mean?

Comment: Please use universal measurements, and avoid using local words like *lac* or *lakh*, which you can see not everyone understands. And for @stef, lac / lakh is Indian word for 100 000.

Comment: Thanks James, I will keep this in mind next time